# In Chapter 3 of the Tomb of Annihilation adventure, where does this encounter take place?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, tomb-of-annihilation

This question concerns an encounter that occurs in Chapter 3 of *Tomb of Annihilation*:

> In Chapter 3, the characters encounter vegepygmies in [area 5, the "Great Rift](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/toa/dwellers-of-the-forbidden-city#5GreatRift)". On the [map of Omu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFdpR.jpg), the marker ⑤ appears *in* the lake of lava. However, the encounter with the vegepygmies occurs on the cliffs above the lava lake. The text says:
>
>  "The first time the characters arrive, they encounter a small vegepygmy tribe preparing to sacrifice a **grung** to the rift."
>
>  
>  The lip of the rift is over 1000 feet long. Is there any indication that the sacrifice is happening at a **specific** place on the lip of the great rift? Does the location of The Sacrifice of Fire impact anything else that happens in Omu?

Where exactly does this encounter take place?

Answer (score 3):

### Yes

> ”The first time the characters arrive”  they will arrive at a particular place.

That’s where it’s happening.

Comment: The *yes* title feels a bit strange, as there are about 4 different questions in the OP's question.

Comment: Not sure this answers anything.